# How can I use a remote shutter release during IR photography with a D3s without leaking into the image?

Tags: nikon, sensor, shutter, infrared

I'm using a D3s for infrared photography.  I'm trying to use a shutter remote to take the images, but the remote's IR-emitting LED/photodiode is emitting enough light to leak into my image on the sensor. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What camera do you have?

Comment: Nikon D3s.
Connected post:
http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/73554/bright-image-with-infrared-d3s-and-cap-on-image-included

Comment: @scottb I'm not sure if this IR sensor which is inside the body, related to remote shutter release.

Comment: sorry, I completely misread what you were talking about. Corrected title.

Comment: Are you trying to take infrared images? Are you talking about making the sensor more infrared sensitive?

Comment: @inkista I´m taking IR images. In "shutter control unit" there is an IR emitting LED / photodiode which tells the camera exactly the time a shutter needs to open an close. This IR source leaks into CMOS leaving a bright pattern in the image meaning you can´t acquire IR images with high ISO.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with an IR remote, you'll need to switch to either an RF (radio frequency) remote, or use a cable release instead. The IR remote requires an IR signal to trip your shutter. And while this works great for visible light photography, it will have an effect on IR photography, as you've found.  If you block the IR or stop it from being transmitted, your remote won't work.

There are radio-based remote triggers that you can use, where the receiver plugs into the cable release port of the camera, and you use the transmitter in hand as your remote--many cheap manual flash remote triggers can do double duty as both a flash remote and a shutter remote.  And you could also use a physical cable release, as long as you're standing nearby behind the camera, and not attempting, say, a self portrait with yourself in the shot.

Answer (score 0):

> What is an IR-sensor of the shutter? For shutter release?

It sounds like you're talking about an infra-red receiver that allows a wireless remote control to trip the shutter, like this:

[image: nikon remote]

> Can I disable it (software-wise or hardware-wise) or remove it to prevent leakage of IR into CMOS when IR-filter is removed?

If you really are talking about the sensor for the IR remote, there shouldn't be anything that you need to disable. It's the remote that would emit any infra-red light -- the sensor only detects it. I'm not sure where the sensor is on this camera (it's built into the body on most Canon cameras), but even if it's inside the body near the image sensor it shouldn't cause a problem.

**Update:**

> I'm using a D3s for infrared photography. I'm trying to use a shutter remote to take the images, but the remote's IR-emitting LED/photodiode is emitting enough light to leak into my image on the sensor.

Using an infrared remote to take a photo in the infrared spectrum is obviously problematic, but there are at least two options:

1. Use the remote from a point that's visible to the IR sensor on the camera but still outside the image sensor's field of view. The IR sensor is usually located somewhere on the front of the camera body and should have a pretty wide field of view.
2. Set the camera to one of its timer modes, so that the shutter fires e.g. 2 seconds after you press the button. That should allow plenty of time to release the button on the remote so that it stops transmitting.

Comment: No I geuss It's not for the remote control. It only shines when the shutter goes up and down.

Comment: I tried to use exposure delay mode, but it give only the delay at first and in the end the shutter closes as the mirror goes down.